# How do you make a reusable UDF that operates on a single column?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Instead of writing a query like

```
select * from xyz where mydomain IN ('foobar.com', 'www.example.com')
```

I want to write a function like

```
select * from xyz where one_of_my_domains(select mydomain as from_site)
```

But I want to be able to reuse this functions for any url in one of many tables. Currently when I use a function like this, I have to predefined what is returned and use it on the whole FROM part of the SQL statement. Is there any way to generalize a UDF to where I can use it on just 1 column instead of it operating over all rows. Here is my code right now that works but I have to predefine every output column which makes it not reusable.

```
domains = ['foobar.com', 'www.example.com'];

// The UDF
function has_domain(row, emit) {
  var has_domain = false;
  if (row.to_site !== null && row.to_site !== undefined) {
    for (var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++){
    if (domains[i] === String.prototype.toLowerCase.call(row.to_site)){
      has_domain = true;
      break;
     }
   }
  }
  return emit({has_domain: has_domain, trackingEventId: row.trackingEventId, date: row.date, from_site: row.from_site, to_site: row.to_site});
}


// UDF registration
bigquery.defineFunction(
  'has_domain',  // Name used to call the function from SQL

  ['from_site'],  // Input column names

  // JSON representation of the output schema
  [{name: 'has_domain', type: 'boolean'}],

  has_domain  // The function reference
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [scalar UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions) using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/). They're much less awkward to use compared to those of legacy SQL.

Comment: The scalar UDFs are exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It might look a little messy  - but below does exactly what you asked!
Make sure you are in Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql))

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION one_of_my_domains(x STRING, a ARRAY<STRING>)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
  (x IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(a)));

WITH xyz AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'foobar.com' AS mydomain UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'www.google.com' AS mydomain
), 
site AS (
  SELECT 'foobar.com' AS domain UNION ALL
  SELECT 'www.example.com' AS domain
)
SELECT * 
FROM xyz 
WHERE one_of_my_domains(mydomain, ARRAY((SELECT domain FROM site)))
```